# Writing a linux script for tcpdump for stopping and running again but save the info in another file

Tags: linux, scripting

I am new to writing script and not sure whether I am correct in writing such script for tcpdump to collect pcap info.

```
tcpdump -s 0 port ftp or ssh or http or https -i eth0 -w mycap.pcap 
#run the tcpdump and store all the info in mycap.pcap

sudo kill -2 #for exit purpose
```

This enables me to run tcpdump which is good, however, I wish to stop this (due to the space for mycap.pcap meet the max capacity of 3GB per file) automatically via the same script and run again but this time round, I will store it in another file (eg. mycap1.pcap)

Then the cycle goes again until I stop the process by pressing crtl+c

Can this be done?

Comment: The purpose of the script to me isn't quite clear - what do you mean by "due to the space for mycap.pcap is full"?  If it filled up the file-system restarting the process with a different filename won't do you much good...

Comment: Sorry my bad, because I keep linking it to my projects. max capacity of 3GB per file. so after it hit the max capacity, it will stop and it will create another file and run the tcpdump again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write a script for that.

```
tcpdump  -C <filesize> -s 0 port ftp or ssh or http or https -i eth0 -w mycap.pcap
```

Have a look at the man-page for tcpdump.

Comment: yea thanks for the solution! I have tried and it work! I also further discover some options which can set the duration as well